# How to determine H in a Kalman filter to translate GPS coordinates to meters

Tags: linear-algebra, kalman-filter

I have a Kalman filter that uses location as part of its internal state. This location is expressed as x, y coordinates in meters north and west from a fixed point (the home location).

Part of my measurements for the filter are GPS coordinates. Can I translate the measurements back to the state space using the H matrix? The range of movement for the tracked object is small enough that I can use a fixed multiplier to scale the longitude to meters. But how do I add the transpose to the matrix, so that the GPS coordinates use the home location as the origin?

Comment: I posted an answer below. I wasn't sure what you meant about adding the transpose to the matrix, so let me know if I misunderstood what you're asking and I can modify my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining some notation first. We'll call latitude $\phi$ and longitude $\lambda$. Let $\phi_\mathrm{ref}$ and $\lambda_\mathrm{ref}$ be the latitude and longitude of the origin of your $x, y$ coordinate system. You said that you have the multipliers that scales the longitude to meters as well; let those be called $m_\phi$ and $m_\lambda$.

Once GPS gives you a measurement $(\phi, \lambda)$, you can translate that into your coordinate system
\begin{align}
x_\mathrm{GPS} &= m_\phi (\phi - \phi_\mathrm{ref}) \\
y_\mathrm{GPS} &= m_\phi (\lambda - \lambda_\mathrm{ref}).
\end{align}
Your measurement function $\bar{h}$ could then just be $[x_\mathrm{GPS}, y_\mathrm{GPS}]^T$. The $H$ matrix that you are asking about would just have ones in the entries corresponding to the $x, y$ position states in your state vector, and zeros elsewhere. So if your state vector is $[x, y, v_x, v_y]^T$, for example, then your $H$ matrix would be
$$
H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, I need to handle the transpose outside of the Kalman filter. I was wondering if I could do it using just the H matrix.

Comment: I'm still not sure that I understand what you mean, but I added a little more onto my answer. If you have $n_z$ measurements and $n_x$ states, then your $H$ matrix needs to be an $n_z \times n_x$ matrix, which can then be given to the filter. Does that answer your question?